# boost::interprocess memory size

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, boost-interprocess

I have a `managed_shared_memory` objects that holds the map container `SharedMap` defined as follows.

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, T> ValueType;
typedef allocator<ValueType, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;
typedef map<std::string, T, std::less<std::string>, ShmemAllocator> SharedMap;
```

My issue is I need to determine the size of shared memory that I am using. The key of the map is a std::string of unknown size, and the data is a template type of unknown size where each data will varying in size.

Can anyone suggest how I can keep track of the memory I am using?

I'm new to boost::interprocess so any suggestion will help greatly.

Comment: My suggestion is to look at the answer I gave on your previous question, which explains why this code is wrong, and which you completely ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by using exception handling. I insert into the map until a `bad_alloc` exception is thrown. I catch the exception and re-size the shared memory.

---

I used the method `static bool grow(const char *shmname, size_type extra_bytes)` which should be a member function of `managed_shared_memory`